# JavaFX FontMetrics

Tags: fonts, javafx

I'm trying to place text accurately in the centre of a pane both horizontally and vertically. Using fontmetrics and a test program I get the following results:

[image]

This test raises the following questions:

1. Why is the ascent value (top black line) so high? I expected it to go across the top of the 'T'. The magenta line is the 'lineheight' value, so I assume that's the baseline for any text above it.
2. If the black line includes line spacing, why is there no measurement for the top of the 'T'?
3. Is there a way to get an accurate bounding box or do I have to graphically linescan a text image to find the boundaries? Obviously the left and right values also include some sort of spacing, so a scan would seem to be the only solution.

Comment: See [leading](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/tk/FontMetrics.java).

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that, but getMaxAscent() is the same value as getAscent() and is NOT the distance from the baseline to top of the character. It gives the top black line in my image above. There are no characters in that font that extend up to the black line.

Comment: This question is tagged `javafx`, should it be?  As far as I know, font metrics data is not exposed in the [JavaFX API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/overview-summary.html), so the question would not seem to be directly related to JavaFX.

Comment: You may wish to share your test program by placing its code in the question.

Comment: Frank: Correct. "[*Leading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fontconcepts.html) is the recommended distance from the bottom of the descender line to the top of the next line."

Comment: @jewelsea: I defer to you on the tag question.

Comment: With Frank's self-answer, it is clear that the tag is correct and this is a JavaFX application.  To get at the font metrics used internally in the Oracle JavaFX implementation, Frank uses `com.sun.javafx` APIs which are not part of the supported `javafx.` apis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting I've come up with this solution:

[image]

Here is the code that produces it:

```
public void getBoundingBox(String s, Font myFont) {                             

    final FontMetrics fm = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(myFont); 

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fm.computeStringWidth(s), fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent());        
    final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.setFill(Color.RED);                  // Just an abitrary color
    gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.TOP);           // This saves having to scan the bottom
    gc.setFont(myFont);

    gc.fillText(s, -fm.getLeading(), 0);    // This saves having to scan the left

    // Get a snapshot of the canvas
    final WritableImage image = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
    final PixelReader pr = image.getPixelReader();

    final int h = (int) canvas.getHeight();
    final int w = (int) canvas.getWidth();

    int x;
    int y = 0;

    // Scan from the top down until we find a red pixel

    boolean found = false;
    while (y < h && !found) {
        x = 0;
        while (x < w && !found) {
            found = pr.getColor(x, y).equals(Color.RED);
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    int yPos = y - 2;

    // Scan from right to left until we find a red pixel

    x = w;        
    found = false;
    while (x > 0 && !found) {
        y = 0;           
        while (y < h && !found) {
            found = pr.getColor(x, y).equals(Color.RED);
            y++;
        }
        x--;
    }
    int xPos = x + 3;

    // Here is a visible representation of the bounding box

    Rectangle mask = new Rectangle(0, yPos, xPos, h - yPos);

    mask.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.25));       
    root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, mask);   // root is a global AnchorPane

    System.out.println("The width of the bounding box is " + xPos);
    System.out.println("The height of the bounding box is " + (h - yPos));
}
```

Two imports are required for FontMetrics:

```
 import com.sun.javafx.tk.FontMetrics;
 import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit;
```

and call the boundingbox like this for example:

```
 Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 100.0); 
 getBoundingBox("Testing", myFont);
```

It solves my problem and I hope this is useful for others as well.

Comment: I've successfully used the Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(..) as you describe, but the com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit as well as com.sun.javafx.tk.FontMetrics are 'internal' packages. Does anybody know a way to get equivalent information with only public javafx.* packages? See also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090775

Comment: In Java9, fm.computeStringWidth(String) has been replaced with getCharWidth(char), so this example no longer works.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an alternate implementation of Frank's `reportSize` function:

```
public void reportSize(String s, Font myFont) {
    Text text = new Text(s);
    text.setFont(myFont);
    Bounds tb = text.getBoundsInLocal();
    Rectangle stencil = new Rectangle(
            tb.getMinX(), tb.getMinY(), tb.getWidth(), tb.getHeight()
    );

    Shape intersection = Shape.intersect(text, stencil);

    Bounds ib = intersection.getBoundsInLocal();
    System.out.println(
            "Text size: " + ib.getWidth() + ", " + ib.getHeight()
    );
}
```

This implementation uses [shape intersection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) to determine the size of the bounding box of the rendered shape with no whitespace.  The implementation does not rely on `com.sun` package classes which may not be directly accessible to user application code in Java 9+.