# Determining width and height of a JavaFX Font

Tags: java, javafx

I have a [Font](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) object and I need both the width and height of the font. I know that the [getSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#getSize()) returns the height of the font as the [point-size of a font is generally the height](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/font-size.htm), but I'm at a loss when it comes to determining the width of the font.

Alternatively, being able to determine the width of each specific character supported by the Font would also be an acceptable solution.

My best guess is that the width is specified when using the [loadFont](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#loadFont(java.io.InputStream,%20double)) method, but the documentation does not specify whether the size parameter represents the width or the height of the font.

All fonts being used are mono-space fonts such as *DejaVu Sans Mono*, *GNU FreeMono*, and *Lucida Sans Unicode*.

Comment: The width of a single char depends on the graphics context you want to use your font in. If you want to use your font for a text string this could be helpful: [How to calculate the pixel width of a String in javaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13015698/7274990)

Comment: Also see related: [JavaFX FontMetrics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237048/javafx-fontmetrics)

Answer (score 4):

I have run into the same problem, and there seems to be no easy way. My solution was to create a `Text` element with the correct font and check it's size:

```
double computeTextWidth(Font font, String text, double wrappingWidth) {
    Text helper = new Text();
    helper.setFont(font);
    helper.setText(text);
    // Note that the wrapping width needs to be set to zero before
    // getting the text's real preferred width.
    helper.setWrappingWidth(0);
    helper.setLineSpacing(0);
    double w = Math.min(helper.prefWidth(-1), wrappingWidth);
    helper.setWrappingWidth((int)Math.ceil(w));
    double textWidth = Math.ceil(helper.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
    return textWidth;
}
```

If I remember correctly the trick here is to set `prefWidth` to -1. See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth-double-).

Answer (score 0):

```
FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(font);
float charWidth = metrics.computeStringWidth("a");
float charHeight = metrics.getLineHeight();
```

Comment: Where is `Toolkit` imported from? I'm only getting the `java.awt.*` one.

Comment: @sorbet For future readers: `Toolkit` is in `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit`. It's a private internal API.